# iOS simulator Xcode 7 intermittently showing nodes

Tags: xcode7

Not sure why this is happening. I've set up a game in sprite kit using objective c and the code seems to work fine as I can see the nodes in the simulator - problem is that 4 times out of 5 the nodes don't show up- Then I stop and run again and it is running okay. Is there some simple reason for this? I have cleaned the program and it is still happening. No compiler errors showing in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Xcode 7, testing on is9?
if so it might be a bug with Apple's texture atlas.

Try using image.xcassets to create a texture atlas then load your images from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Z-Position. If all the nodes have the same Z-Position some nodes will appear sometimes and some nodes won't, like you described. The higher the Z-Position, the closer the node is to the viewer.